# Setting properties on @ViewChildren in Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

In my html template I'm having multiple  elements generated by *ngFor.

I am successfully able to subscribe to their value changes in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

However, I am *not* able to **set** the .checked property via code.

Does somebody spot my error? Any help is really appreciated!

```
export class GroupsExpPanelComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren('confirm') confirm: QueryList < MatButtonToggle > ;
  confirmToggles: MatButtonToggle[] = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.confirm.changes
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.confirmToggles = res.toArray();
        }
      );
  }


<mat-button-toggle #confirm>Title</mat-button-toggle>
```

I would have expected to be able to set my properties like so

```
this.confirmToggles[index].checked = true;
```

Comment: Why are you not using view bindings like `<mat-button-toggle [checked="foo">`? That would be much more like things are done in Angular 2 and later.

Comment: I'll try that and refactor some code. Thanks for the suggestion, will come back here and report.

Comment: Thanks Günther, I guess it was too late yesterday. I did some refactoring and am now using property binding like you suggested. Works for me in my specific case!

Comment: Way better if the use case allows it. Glad to hear some sleep solved it :D

Answer (score 0):

this.confirmToggles[index] is a *reference* to a native element, not a native element in and of itself, nor an instance of the MatButtonToggle class.

(<HTMLInputElement> this.confirmToggles[index].nativeElement) might be what you want, assuming that the native element really is a button of some sort. Of course, messing around with native elements isn't really the ideal Angular way of doing things.

If you want to get back instances of your MatButtonToggle class, you need to use @ViewChildren(MatButtonToggle).

Comment: @ViewChildren(MatButtonToggle) would give me all the instances in the componenent, right? What if I want to only query those instances that have been tagged #confirm in the template?

Comment: Maybe @ViewChildren('confirm', {read: MatButtonToggle}) would do the trick? I can't seem to find good documentation of how the read parameter works, but it's supposed to give you some control over the type of objects returned.